# How to read `JSON` object in Angular

Tags: node.js, json, angular, typescript

I have a `API` in my `Node` app like this:

```js
exports.getPlanningStages = async (req, res, next) => {
  const currentPage = req.query.page || 1;
  const perPage = 10;
  try {
    const totalItems = await Planningstage.find().countDocuments();
    const planningstages = await Planningstage.find()
      .populate("creator")
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage)
      .limit(perPage);

    // res.status(200).json(planningstages);
    res.status(200).json({
      planningstages,
      totalItems: totalItems,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

And this is my `HTTP request` in `Angular`:

```js
fetch() {
  this.psService.getPlanningStages().subscribe((resData) => {
    console.log(resData);
  });
}
```

This is the response of my request: [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft3GA.png)

How can I split this `json` into two separate variables?

Comment: Can you attach the console screenshot?

Comment: do you mean `resData.planningstages` and `resData.totalItems`?

Comment: After seeing your console screenshot, you can get it by `resData.planningstages` and `resData.totalItem`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ES6` **Destructuring assignment** feature like this:

```js
 fetch() {
    this.psService.getPlanningStages().subscribe((resData) => {
      const [planningstages, totalitems] = resData;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You are right but the syntax for an object is `const {planningstages, totalItems} = resData` not with `[ ... ]`